# Is "content" an adjective in "those content"?

Tags: grammar

I asked the freelancer I hired why he used **those** with the singular noun **content**.

> Children tend to lack self-control and are extremely vulnerable to
> **those** personalized **content**.

He said **those content** is used and showed me this screenshot:

[image]

Was he trying to fool me? In the screenshot, "content" is an adjective, meaning "those who are content", while, in "those personalized content", content is a noun, isn't it?

Comment: The examples he showed are far too different from his original phrase (2 of those use an entirely unrelated definition of "content"). If someone showed me that, I'd be very confident in concluding that their understanding of English is at a very basic level.

Comment: Actually, changing "those" to "that" will not help in this particular example. I think a better sentence is "Children tend to lack self-control and are extremely vulnerable to [-omitted-] personalized content." or "Children tend to lack self-control and are extremely vulnerable to /such/ personalized content."

Comment: The first and third are contracted forms, meaning something like "those people who are content to ...". In the second, "those" refers to a plural noun phrase "content standards", not the adjective "those" itself.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The word **those** can be used either as a determiner (those houses) or a demonstrative pronoun (those who wish to go).

In your first and third examples, **those** is used as a pronoun, meaning those people. There is no problem here.

**those** is the plural of **that** and I can find no dictionary evidence that **those** can be used as a determiner to modify a singular object.

However in the example quoting the Economist, the phrase **content standards** is a recognised term in the field of education: "*Specifications of what all learners are expected to know and be able to do within a particular field of study, discipline or subject at different grade levels, ages, or other criteria*." Here **those** is modifying **content standards**, not **content**.

So, the person who advised you was wrong. **Those** is always plural.

http://www.ibe.unesco.org/en/glossary-curriculum-terminology/c/content-standards

Comment: +1 And on top of that, he's either either disingenuous or sloppy to show you those examples as support of his use of "those content" since they're irrelevant.

Comment: @gotube I would guess he was just annoyed or felt like he was being interrogated about his grammar, and just googled the phrasing he used and sent a screenshot to end the conversation.

Comment: I guess I can't completely trust that platform. His profile shows that he is a native English speaker based in Canada with his ID verified. He uses Grammarly premium. Except "those content", his work is actually very good. I guess Grammarly is a great software program. I left him a bad review. I read his response to my review. I guess he didn't use Grammarly to improve his response. He doesn't sound like a native speaker in the response. Because he is a top rated freelancer, he was able to remove my bad review.

Comment: Here's his response to my review. Does he sound like a native speaker? Part 1: Please disregard, I’m a brilliant and amazing freelancer with 2 degrees in arts and communications. Here’s what transpired: Very poor client, and wasn’t willing to learn. It’s sad he has gone ahead to drop such a comment on my page. The context of the article was “..It slowly builds a virtual world of fantasies that draws them away from the focus of reality, since children tend to lack self-control and are extremely vulnerable to those personalized content…” ....

Comment: Part 2: after showing him numerous proofs like premium grammarly and a NY times exact quote! He claims a certain “language group” told him the sentence was wrong. I wouldn’t recommend such a client, and it’s a pity I had taken on the job before I figured out.

Comment: @Learner110 I'm suspicious he's not a native speaking Canadian. We never say "*go ahead **to do***". It's "*go ahead **and do***". So in this case, he should have said, "*It's sad he has gone ahead **and dropped** such a comment...*". This is a not the kind of mistake a native speaker would make except as an editing error. And the irony of that!

Answer (score 9):

In the first sentence "content" is a noun, and means (I suppose) "information made available by a website or other electronic medium."

But there are two words spelled "content".

Content¹ means things in a container.  Content² means "happy or satisfy". Content² can be a verb or an adjective.  Moreover content¹ can also be used as a modifier of nouns.

So you get "Those (who are) content² to serve."  Content is an adjective, and "content to serve" is reduced relative clause.  Similarly we have "those (who are) content to let rhythms rock..."  again a reduced relative clause.  In these cases "those" is a pronoun.

And we have "those content¹ standards". Here content is being used as a modifier of the noun "standards".  The determiner "those" agrees with the headword of the noun phrase "standards" and is plural.

These are irrelevant to your sentence.

But if the headword in the noun phrase is singular "content", then the determiner should be singular,  "that personalized content".  Perhaps no demonstrative determiner is required  "Children are vulnerable to personalized content."

Answer (score 3):

In the first and last examples, "those content" is a reduced relative clause, and it means, "*those **who are** content*".

"Those" is a pronoun, and "content" is an adjective roughly meaning "satisfied".

In the second example, "those content" isn't a constituent phrase at all, as "content standards" is a compound noun, and "those" applies to that noun.

So none of those examples are at all relevant to "those personalized content". They neither support its use nor prove it wrong.